# \hat, \tilde and \bar with beamer-package

Tags: beamer

When using `\hat{}`, `\tilde{}` and `\bar{}` in formulas while also using the `beamer`-package, instead of a bar over the sign I want to use a `\Phi` is drawn, and instead of a hat over the letter a `\Theta` is drawn. Why does that happen, and how can I fix that?

[image]

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{fourier}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Some math in beamer}
  \begin{equation}
    \label{eq:1}
    \hat A \neq A
  \end{equation}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you prowide minimal working example (MWE) starting with `\documentclass{beamer}` and ending with `\end{document}` which will show your problem?

Comment: Will do that as soon as possible

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am no font expert, but it looks like there is a problem with the sans serif math font and `fourier`. A workaround would be to add `\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}`. To cite from the beamer user guide:

> This font theme does not really change any fonts. Rather, it suppresses certain internal replacements performed by beamer.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{fourier}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Some math in beamer}
  \begin{equation}
    \label{eq:1}
    \hat A \neq A
  \end{equation}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]